# Proving an inequality for the Lucas sequence using Strong Induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, proof-explanation, induction

> Define a sequence $a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots$ as follows: $a_1 = 1,$ $a_2 = 3,$ $a_k = a_{k-1} + a_{k-2},$ $\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}, k \geq 3$. This sequence is known as the Lucas sequence. Use strong mathematical induction to prove that $a_n \leq (\frac{7}{4})^n$ $\space \space \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}, n \geq 1$

We've started learning induction/strong induction, however, I'm still a little bit confused if I've successfully proven the above sequence via strong induction. What I have so far:

---

Let $P(n)$ be the statement that $a_n \leq (\frac{7}{4})^n, \forall n \in \mathbb{Z}, n \geq 1$. For the basis, we are given:

$a_1 = 1$
$a_2 = 3$
$a_k = a_{k-1} + a_{k-2}, \space \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}, k\geq 3$

Let $k$ be any integer $\geq 3$ and suppose $P(i)$ is the statement that $a_i \leq (\frac{7}{4})^i, \forall i \in \mathbb{Z}, 1 \leq i \leq k,$ then $P(i) \Longrightarrow P(k+1)$.

---

Do I simply just plug $i = k+1$ in to $a_i$ and $(\frac{7}{4})^i$ then compare like so?

$a_{k+1} = a_k + a_{k-1}$

By the inductive hypothesis:

$a_k + a_{k-1} \leq (\frac{7}{4})^k + (\frac{7}{4})^{k-1}$

$=(\frac{7^{k}}{4^{k}}) + (\frac{7^{k-1}}{4^{k-1}})$

$=(\frac{7^{k+1}}{4^{k+1}})(\frac{4}{7}) + (\frac{7^{k+1}}{4^{k+11}})(\frac{4^2}{7^2})$ by the quotient rule for exponents

$=(\frac{7^{k+1}}{4^{k+1}})[\frac{4}{7} + \frac{4^2}{7^2}]$ by factoring

$=(\frac{7}{4})^{k+1}[\frac{44}{49}] \leq (\frac{7}{4})^{k+1}$ as $\frac{44}{49}$ is clearly $ < 1$

Comment: If you want to use strong induction like this then you need to check enough initial cases, here when $n=1$ and $n=2$, to avoid the [all horses are the same colour problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_horses_are_the_same_color).

Comment: How do you determine the number of base cases to check? With weak induction I know 1 is sufficient, but for strong induction I've had problems where I used 1, 2, 3, or more.

Comment: The proof of the induction step should tell you how many earlier values you need to check initially.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [proving a inequality with fibonacci's sequence using strong induction (given excercise.10)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4568568/proving-a-inequality-with-fibonaccis-sequence-using-strong-induction-given-exc) (that multiduplicate does not deal with the same sequence but the problem is extremely similar)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I start the inductive step in strong induction proof?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1699769/how-do-i-start-the-inductive-step-in-strong-induction-proof) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24a_n%5Cleq(%5Cfrac%7B7%7D%7B4%7D)%5En%24&p=1). There's also other duplicates, e.g., [Let $a_1=1$, $a_2=3$ , and for $n \ge 2$ let $a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}$. Show that $a_n < \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^n$ for all natural numbers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/835321) ...

Comment: (cont.) and [What is the second principle of finite induction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/14984), as well as AoPS threads, e.g., [Induction](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1704025p10959266) (starting in Post #$5$), etc.